# Why my current time zone in app is not changing?

Tags: c#, timezone

I'm new with `c#` and `timezone`.
I'm currently creating an app with a `timezone`.

I have this code to get the current `timezone` of my local machine.

```
 private void btnGetCurrentTimeZone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
     lblShowTimeZone.Text = "TimeZone: " + localZone.StandardName;
 }
```

My problem is when I run the app and click the `button` for the first time I got the correct `timezone`. But when I change the system `timezone` on settings and click again the `button`, the `timezone` value did not change. I need to close the app and run again to get the correct `timezone`.

Comment: You need to show us all the code neccessary to assess any problem. You are talking about "clicking a button", so the complete click handler would be nice to work with. All we have is a single line out of context ...

Comment: It seems like `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` uses a backing field to cache the local time zone the first time you get it. I can't seem to find a way to change this, but if you use `TimeZoneInfo`, you can clear it's cache by calling `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()`, afterwards `TimeZoneInfo.Local` should always have the correct time zone.

Comment: Thanks @Jesse it worked. Thanks for the idea. I just used the `TimeZoneInfo` and clear the cache using `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()`.  What I did is I changed the previous code with this 3 lines of code `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData(); TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local; lblShowTimeZone.Text = "TimeZone: " + timeZone.DisplayName;`

Comment: The .NET Framework is great.  It's handling of Dates, Times and Time Zones is, well...  You may want to look at NodaTime (https://nodatime.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency, instead of calling `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` every time you call `TimeZoneInfo.Local`, you can set an event handler to do this when the system time zone changes:

```
// in some startup init method for your application
SystemEvents.TimeChanged += (s, e) => TimeZoneInfo.ClearCacheData();
```

Now this will only be cleared when/if a user changes the system time zone and you can use `TimeZoneInfo.Local` throughout your application and be confident it reflects the current system time zone and you get the benefit of having that value cached most of the time so it doesn't need to callout to some Win32 method to get the current value everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Use TimeZoneInfo instead of TimeZone; TimeZone is deprecated [reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezone?view=net-6.0).

```
TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
lblShowTimeZone.Text = "TimeZone: " + localZone.StandardName;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For this to work right, the call to `ClearCachedData` should be before `TimeZoneInfo.Local`